# Is ECB mode more suitable than CBC mode while encrypting a long bit string?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, cbc, modes-of-operation, ecb

I know that ECB is less secure than CBC, but will it be suitable for encrypting a long bit string?

Comment: Closely related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58294

Comment: Welcome to Crypto!  You may want to be specific about the length of the string. Do you have anything else to add to your question?

Comment: Do you have continuous bit string like streaming videos or fixed length of bit string as asked by Patriot?

Comment: And is there a reason you can't use AES-GCM instead of either? ECB doesn't even provide IND-CPA security, CBC does but lacks IND-CCA & IND-CCA2 secuity (unless you MAC the ciphertext).